# Cocos2d Displaying a Layer Issue

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, layer, cclayer

I'm trying to display a pause game layer from the applicationDidEnterBackground: method and for some reason it does call the method but nothing happens.

Delegate

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication*)application {
        ship = [[Ship alloc] init];
        [ship pause];
```

Pause Method

```
- (void)pause
{


    BOOL isPaused = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] isPaused];

    if(!isPaused) 
    {
        //Pause the game
        ccColor4B c = {100,100,0,100}; 
        PauseLayer *pauseLayer = [[[PauseLayer alloc] initWithColor:c] autorelease]; 

        [self.leftMenuItem setIsEnabled:NO];
        [self.rightMenuItem setIsEnabled:NO];
        [self.fireMenuItem setIsEnabled:NO];

        [self addChild:pauseLayer z:10 tag:100];
        [[CCDirector sharedDirector] pause];        
    }
}
```

PauseLayer

```
+ (id)scene
{
    CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];
    PauseLayer *layer = [PauseLayer node];
    [scene addChild:layer];
    return scene;
}


- (id)initWithColor:(ccColor4B)color
{
    if((self = [super initWithColor:color])) 
    {
        self.isTouchEnabled = YES; 
        [CCMenuItemFont setFontName:@"Marker Felt"];
        [CCMenuItemFont setFontSize:40];

        CCMenuItemFont *resumeGameItem = [CCMenuItemFont itemFromString:@"Resume" target:self selector:@selector(resumeGame)];
        CCMenuItemFont *menuGameItem = [CCMenuItemFont itemFromString:@"Menu" target:self selector:@selector(goToGameMenu)];

        CCMenu *menu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:resumeGameItem,menuGameItem,nil];
        [menu alignItemsVerticallyWithPadding:40.00];

        [self addChild:menu];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you init the ship in the delegate, it isn't added to any cocos layer that I can see.  you would have to get a reference to the current scene and add the ship to it (assuming ship is a sub-class of Cocos node).

Comment: Hi, thank you for you answer, all of my class inherit from CCLayer, it still calls the method but nothing happens

Comment: How does the ship get added to a cocos layer?  I don't see it in the code above.  The AppDelegate isn't a cocos node.  Ship has to be added to a layer for it to show.

Comment: Use CCDirector to get the current scene and add the ship to it.